# How to write query to get cumulative sum group by month and year?

Tags: mysql

i have below table

```
id      Dates           Amount
1   20170221    -192161
2   20170222    884
3   20170223    -74
4   20170227    961
5   20170321    -292161
6   20170322    994
7   20170323    -44
8   20170327    691
```

i want output as below

```
id      Dates           Amount   Cumulative
1   20170221    -192161   -192161
2   20170222    884   -191277
3   20170223    -74   -191351
4   20170227    961   -190390
5   20170321    -292161   -482551
6   20170322    994   -481557
7   20170323    -44   -481601
8   20170327    691   -480910
```

i have write this query but did not get desired output

```
select id
     , DATE_FORMAT(Dates,'%b-%Y')Dates
     , Amount
     , @total := @total + Amount as cumulative_sum
  from mytable
     , (Select @total := 0) as total;
```

i want cumulative sum of all day of the month when i am apply group by month clause it return me only first row of the month

Answer (score 1):

One option which should work on all versions of MySQL would be to use a correlated subquery to find the cumulative sum:

```
SELECT
    id,
    Dates,
    Amount,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.Amount) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.id) Cumulative
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY id;
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, then we can try using `SUM` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    id,
    Dates,
    Amount,
    SUM(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY id) Cumulative
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

### Demo

Comment: the query provided by you that already i have tried but i want to group by month but i want all day's cumulative of that particular month e.g i have 4 records of february month i want group it in one but i want 4 cumulative records of that month -Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: I have given you two queries each of which exactly generates the output you are expecting.  If you have some other question, then maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: i appreciate that you gave me solution but i have mentioned my problem as "i want cumulative sum of all day of the month when i am apply group by month clause it return me only first row of the month"